# Route all traffic through proxy

Tags: proxy

My school uses a proxy with authentication to filter the internet. I have a Node.js script that needs to establish a connection to another server via non-http ports ( >1024). How do I send all of my internet connections, even processes that are started by root, through this proxy on Linux. I want to make it so that Linux authenticates with my username and password automatically so that nodejs doesn't have to authenticate with it.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04